# Using contains operator to add new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a DataFrame imported from an excel file, we can say expenses of different type. This DataFrame has a column called 'CONCEPT'. I would like to add two new columns depending on the type of expense. To do so, I identify "key words" in the concept. For instance>

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
      "DATE" : ['12/02/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '10/02/2023'],    
      "CONCEPT" : ['Supermarket','Restaurant', 'petrol station', 'decathlon'],
      "EUR" : [-150,-50,-45,-95]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

df['EXPENSE TYPE'] = pd.Series(dtype="string")

df['EXPENSE TYPE'][df['CONCEPT'].str.upper().str.contains('SUPERMARKET')] = 'FOOD'
df['EXPENSE TYPE'][df['CONCEPT'].str.upper().str.contains('RESTAURANT')] = 'FOOD'
df['EXPENSE TYPE'][df['CONCEPT'].str.upper().str.contains('PETROL')] = 'GAS'
df['EXPENSE TYPE'][df['CONCEPT'].str.upper().str.contains('DECATHLON')] = 'CLOTHES'
```

With this code I get the expected output>

```
         DATE         CONCEPT  EUR EXPENSE TYPE
0  12/02/2023     Supermarket -150         FOOD
1  02/01/2023      Restaurant  -50         FOOD
2  02/01/2023  petrol station  -45          GAS
3  10/02/2023       decathlon  -95      CLOTHES
```

However, I would like to add two fields instead of one. So when I identify the word 'Supermarket' I add the EXPENSE TYPE and a SUBCATEGORY, for instance:

```
         DATE         CONCEPT  EUR EXPENSE TYPE  SUBCATEGORY
0  12/02/2023     Supermarket -150         FOOD         HOME
1  02/01/2023      Restaurant  -50         FOOD  OUT OF HOME
2  02/01/2023  petrol station  -45          GAS       DIESEL
3  10/02/2023       decathlon  -95      CLOTHES        SPORT
```

How could I add two new columns instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.apply` with a suitable function:

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
      "DATE" : ['12/02/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '10/02/2023'],    
      "CONCEPT" : ['Supermarket','Restaurant', 'petrol station', 'decathlon'],
      "EUR" : [-150,-50,-45,-95]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

def func(row):
    s = row['CONCEPT'].upper()
    if 'SUPERMARKET' in s:
        r = 'FOOD', 'HOME'
    elif 'RESTAURANT' in s:
        r = 'FOOD', 'OUT OF HOME'
    elif 'PETROL' in s:
        r = 'GAS' , 'DIESEL'
    elif 'DECATHLON' in s:
        r = 'CLOTHES', 'SPORT'
    else:
        r = 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN'
    row['EXPENSE TYPE'] = r[0]
    row['SUBCATEGORY'] = r[1]
    return row
    
df = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

which gives

```
         DATE         CONCEPT  EUR EXPENSE TYPE  SUBCATEGORY
0  12/02/2023     Supermarket -150         FOOD         HOME
1  02/01/2023      Restaurant  -50         FOOD  OUT OF HOME
2  02/01/2023  petrol station  -45          GAS       DIESEL
3  10/02/2023       decathlon  -95      CLOTHES        SPORT
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the *contains* operator as in the real case, I won't have just 4 cases. So the idea is to define both new entries in the same line

Comment: You could loop through the rows using an IF expression involving .contains and then setting multiple columns but this won't be one line and is less efficient than .apply as above which could be modified for any number of cases. I've edited the code so the new values are in one line; this is clear and efficient with no repetition; it processes about 1000 rows a second.